# DVI + HDMI connected Monitors = Color difference

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, display, colors

I've just bought 2 identical 23" monitors, **Acer V233H** to be precise.

On my graphics card (**ATI Radeon HD4870**), I have 3 outputs. **1 HDMI**, **1 DVI** (or maybe DVI-I?) and another one that I haven't seen before (it's not VGA though).

So 1 of the monitors is connected directly via DVI, where as the other one is connected via an DVI-to-HDMI converter and inside the HDMI port of my graphics card.

The color difference between them is quite significant, the HDMI one is a lot cleaner and brighter even though I've reset all settings (both on the ATI card and the monitor).

**Could this really be due to the converter, or am I missing something obvious?**

Comment: The one you haven't seen before could be [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).

Comment: That's the one :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably differences in the monitors. The signal being fed to both is digital, so the cables and converter are able to preserve the contents exactly as they transfer the signal to the monitors.

Your best bet is to adjust the monitors until they are as close as possible.

Comment: Manually? Ughhhhh :(

Comment: @Marko Eh, it takes about 5 minutes and you only have to do it once. It could be worse! You could have three monitors, like myself! You get two synced up just right, just to find out that the third doesn't go that far and you have to start all over :P

Answer (score 1):

An HDMI to DVI adapter doesn't convert or change the signal in any way.  DVI-D (or the digital component of DVI-I) are identical except for the plug/pinout.

Identical monitors can have distinct differences.

One thing to consider... is it possible that one of your monitors is using the analog portion of the DVI?  It might also be possible that your monitors are using a different display profile for HDMI vs. your DVI, but I doubt it.  (Some monitors try to be intelligent, enhancing color for DVDs and what not.)

Comment: All the settings I could think of have been reset and I've checked them manually. There is NO difference between the setup of the 2 whatsoever.

Comment: Swap the cables on the two monitors... see if the color issues reverse as well.  If so, I'd assume that your monitors are using the analog portion of your DVI.

Answer (score 0):

90% it's due to AMD/Nvidia using [different](https://pcmonitors.info/articles/correcting-hdmi-colour-on-nvidia-and-amd-gpus/) pixel formats over different video interfaces.

Remainder 10% is your monitor being dumb and applying wrong RGB color space on its end. 
For example, on my Samsung (when YCbCr mode is not used) "[HDMI black levels](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/TVs/Samsung-HDMI-Black-Levels-Explanation/td-p/71244)" option gets unlocked.

And depending on its value it may screw between 0-255/16-235 modes.